# how to iterate through 3x3 window of an array?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, sliding-window

I have used following code to print array of size (189,101) in 3x3 window.further I want to put a condition which should be applicable on each window of size 3x3. How to iterate through each (3,3) array differently?
Here is the modified code to generate array in (3,3) window.

```
from itertools import islice
 np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
 img=gdal.Open(path)
  arr = np.array([[1,2,3,4],
           [2,3,4,5],
           [3,4,5,6],
           [4,5,6,7]])

 def rolling_window(a, shape):
s = (a.shape[0] - shape[0] + 1,) + (a.shape[1] - shape[1] + 1,) + shape
strides = a.strides + a.strides

return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=s, strides=strides)

 def window2(arr, shape=(3,3)):
     r_extra = np.floor(shape[0] / 2).astype(int)
     c_extra = np.floor(shape[1] / 2).astype(int)
       out = np.empty((arr.shape[0] + 2 * r_extra, arr.shape[1] + 2 * c_extra))
#print(out)
out[:] = np.nan
out[r_extra:-r_extra, c_extra:-c_extra] = arr
view = rolling_window(out, shape)
#print(view)
for i in range(len(view)):
    for j in range(len(view[i])):
        i=0
        j=range(0,4)
        i+=1
        for x in view[i,j]:
            np.apply_along_axis(np.any, 0, x == 4)
            print(x)
        #print(view[i,j])
#print(len(view[i,j]))

 window2(arr, (3,3))
```

Output :

```
   [[ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
   [  1.   1.   1.   1.   1.]
   [  1.   1.   1.   1.   1.]
   [  1.   1.   1.   1.   1.]
   [  1.   1.   1.   1.   1.]]


  [[ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
  [  1.   1.   1.   1.   1.]
  [  1.   1.   1.   1.   1.]
  [  1.   1.   1.   1.   1.]
  [  1.   1.   1.   1.   1.]]


  [[ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
  [  1.   1.   1.   1.   1.]
  [  1.   1.   1.   1.   1.]
  [  1.   1.   1.   1.   1.]
  [  1.   1.   1.   1.   1.]]
```

What I need is to print or highlight value which is not equal to 1 in each window size 3x3. What can be done here?

Comment: Could you create a minimal example one can run along with your desired output?!

Comment: @Cleb I have edited with the required output.

Comment: Could you please replace the tif image with some source code so people can just run it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100 % sure what you are trying to do but if `x` is your result view, you could do something like

```
np.apply_along_axis(np.any, 0, x == 1)
```

or

```
np.any(x == 1, axis=0)
```

Comment: Yes x is my result view I wanted values 4 and above but this does not seem to work. i have replaced my input array with dummy value. @Joe

Comment: I have updated my source code to fulfill the purpose but the condition of getting values more than 4 is not working rest is good.

Comment: Do you need `np.apply_along_axis(np.any, 0, x == j)` ? By the way, `apply_along_axis` is not a very good function, it basically is a `for` loop. Usually you use it to prototype your code, once it is working you can replace it with much faster NumPy equivalents.

Comment: I am not getting desired output anyway. J had tried normal condition for x but it is giving wrong output. There may be some mistake in third For loop which leads to give wrong output. @Joe

Comment: The reason might be that you are not assigning the return value of `np.apply_along_axis(np.any, 0, x == 4)` to a variable. This expression does not modify the array in-place. Try something like `y = np.apply_along_axis(np.any, 0, x == 4); print(y)`